# sapui5: Load initially NDA page and load Shell later

Tags: sapui5

i've a requirement as below after use logs-in:
- user will first see a nda agreement page, where he has to sign on it and submit
- then after sumit, it has to load shell and then he cont with other screens in shell

the key here is, if any time the user refreshes the screen.. it should always takes him to shell and not the the nda screen. as we've to remember the user's decision and load only shell.

-wt is the best way to handle this?
-i hope (prefer) to do this in the same ui5 project only.. rather than 2 different projs.
-how do we remember the user's decision? its a kind of session handling within ui5!
-do we've to use content.plastAt() from nda page to shell? how to achieve this..!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following in a few ways, lets tackle the NDA remember feature.

You can use javascript's session storage api for example, this will make sure that a refresh will keep the value but a completely new session will show the NDA again.

Now if you want Ui5 based solution for the NDA you can set the first screen as the NDA and in the submit button to navigate to the next page and detach the NDA page from the shell.

Another way to achieve this is by using a modal popup with the NDA and on click just remove the popup
and save the data in the session storage.

Hope this gave you a clear idea.
BR,
Saar

Comment: thanks for ur post. ya some kind of session storage () is needed to capture and if it has value .. always show shell. i need to use below code SessionStorage function and see if it works to my solution. but can u also tell how to detach the nda page and goto shell? i can't bus.publish as its xml/desktop application. please suggest ? do we need to overite the placeAt(content)??

Comment: Hi, add to the shell 2 views 1 the NDA and one the page you need to get to. you can follow this link: [link](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2014/08/26/sapui5-using-shell) after the click on NDA just bus an event and catch it with the shell, and in the shell remove the first page. since you are on the 2nd page you will not see any refresh happening. moreover, you can even use 1 page just for the NDA and in the event change the content of the shell and it will just refresh the content not the shell itself so it will look like you navigated.

Comment: thanks saar. the NDA page should not have anything else other than the NDA statement and check box with a submit button. then it shud go to shell home page (first workset).

Answer (score 0):

you need to use Session Storage to meet your requirement
    In the NDA sign on page check  sessionStorage data  and in the controller of NDA  write this code

```
onInit: function() {
            var oView = this.getView();
            oView.addEventDelegate({
            onBeforeShow : jQuery.proxy(function(evt) {
                this.onBeforeShow();
            }, this)
        });


    },
onBeforeShow: function(){

        if(SessionStorage['UserName'])
        {

                sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus().publish("nav", "to", { 
                    id : "idShell",//id to navigate to shell Page
                    data : {}
                });
        }   
            else
                {
                   // DO SOMTHING

                }
```

}

Comment: thanks for ur post. will use the session storage function and let you know. but i can't use bus.publish method to navigated to shell. how to i navigate to shell on submit of nda? i guess it would be same on refresh also.